# limit calculation to infinity 123

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

If $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)= +\infty$, prove that 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{x(f(x)^2) + 2f(x) + x}{x(f(x)^2) + xf(x) + 2f(x) - 3}= 1.$$

Comment: Note:  I edited your question pretty heavily.  Please check that I didn't change your meaning.

Comment: @lulu We seem to have submitted a similar edit simultaneously, but I don't have the edit privilege yet. Could you please check everything is ok? Feel free to reject my edit if it's better to do so.

Comment: @lulu the meaning hasn't been changed. thank you for the edit, I didn't know how to properly type in my question.

Comment: @yo' I don't see your edit in the queue...do you think mine looks right?  The OP just approved it which is a good sign.

Comment: @guest Not a problem.  If you are interested, this quick tutorial shows you just about everything you need to use the formatting syntax:  http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  Divide the numerator by $x(f(x))^2$, divide the denominator by $x(f(x))^2$.

Comment: Note that $x\ne 0$ because $x\to\infty$.

Comment: We also need that $f(x)$ is not 0 at infinity. But that is no problem here.

Comment: @mathreadler, yes, thanks for the comment.